# Schwinn AC Performance Plus with Carbon Blue Pedal Exchange

Tags: parts, pedals, spd, indoor, schwinn

I want to switch out the pedals on my Schwinn AC Performance Plus with Carbon Blue for the Venzo 3-in-1 pedals (I only use SPDs & don’t like the sneaker cages). On the Venzos, the part that attaches to the crank is too small. Is there an adapter or a part I can buy to make them compatible with the Schwinn?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  It would help make your question clearer if you could include photos of the parts and indicate where he problems are.

Comment: The Venzos should have 9/16 threaded axles which is the larger size. The only thing I can think of that's larger would be pedals with a taper axle. Did the Schwinn come with threadless taper pedals?